# Making an interrogative sentence from affirmative sentence

Tags: questions

Affirmative sentence:

> I want him to buy this gift for me.

I want to make an interrogative sentence like

> whom do I want to buy this gift? ".

But I'm not sure if it's correct. Because it can be interpreted as asking about the specific person whom I want to buy that gift  as well as asking about the specific person for whom I want to buy that gift.

So should I use something like these:

1. Whom do I want to buy this gift for? *or* For whom do I want to buy this gift?
2. Whom do I want to buy this gift for me?

Comment: I don't see an indirect object in your example.

Comment: @BillJ what about him ? isn't it an indirect object?

Comment: No: "him" is direct object of "want". The infinitival clause "to buy this gift for me" is not object but complement of "want".

Comment: I'm sure there'll be a lot of comments from the peanut gallery about "who" vs. "whom," about how "whom" is technically correct and proper but how "who" is by and large what people would actually say. Also, it's worth commenting that "buy" is ditransitive, so many people would say "buy me this gift" instead of "buy this gift for me," not that there's anything wrong with the latter.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman whom do i want to buy me this gift?  And how would you make a question that I want with the latter.  is the following question correct ? "whom do I want to buy this gift for me? "

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your help

Comment: Original: (1) I want him to buy this gift for me. [unmarked; plain statement of fact, but ambiguous (and hence best avoided) without context.] // Disambiguated declarative sentences: (2) I want _him_ to buy this gift for me. [stress indicates identification of who the desired benefactor is] /   (3) I want him to buy this gift for _me_. [stress indicated identification of who the desired recipient is] /  (4) I want _him_ to buy this gift **for** me. [stresses emphasise that you don't want to buy it yourself: you want an agent to do it {though you may well imburse him}].

Comment: Start with a simple sentence instead of a complex one if you want to see how the rule works. This example gets mixed up with complements and case and never gets to making a question.

Answer (score 1):

> I want him to buy this gift for me.

"Whom do I want to buy this gift?" is not correct. The questions in "1." are not correct either ("Whom do I want to buy this gift for? or For whom do I want to buy this gift?"); the reason is that "I" is not the subject of "buy". Question "2." is  correct.

You say "I want to make an interrogative sentence like…"; this does not mean anything precise. There are at least six interrogative sentences that you can construct on the basis of the information given in the affirmative sentence.

- Who wants him to buy this gift for me?
- Whom do I want to buy this gift for me?
- What do I want him to do?
- What do I want him to buy for me?
- Whom do I want him to buy a gift for? (*depending on interpretation, grammatical equivalent of indirect object*)
- On behalf of whom do I want him to buy this gift? (*depending on interpretation, adverbial*)

In order to be specific, you have to be more precise;

I want to make an interrogative sentence that has to do with

- who does the action of the main verb. (*I*)
- who does the action of the infinitive verb. (*him*)
- what the object of main verb  is. (*him to buy this gift for me*)
- what  the object of the infinitive verb is. (*this gift*)
- who or what the recipient of the infinitive verb is . (*me*)
- on behalf of whom  the action of the infinitive verb is done. (*me*)

In questions that bear upon the noun group in complex transitive structures, both "who" and "whom" are used, but "whom" is somewhat more frequent.

---

[who](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22who%20does%20he%20want%20to%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Who does he want to speak for him if he cannot speak for himself because he is ...

because who is there to ask to open the door, and who does he want to open it?

Who does he want to get it ?

---

[whom](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whom+does+he+want+to%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APwXEde4PiZ8RoaxgRfOdI3-Vt7psfojlw:1685884198356&ei=Jo18ZOOrFb6pkdUPqbubqAg&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjj1pmG2Kn_AhW-VKQEHandBoU4ZBDy0wN6BAgkEAQ&biw=1280&bih=663&dpr=1.5)

When an investor buys a share in the fund , whom does he want to control his money ?

Whom does he want to stand by him once he crosses the bridge?

perhaps also 'whom does he want to fail him?

Whom does he want to go first?